# Javascript validation not recognizing that date field has been filled

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate a form with javascript to check if a date field has been filled by selecting from a pop-up calendar.

```
<label for="datepicker" class="general short">Due Date</label>
<input name="due_date" id="datepicker" class="textbox long_field" type="text">
```

The `id="datepicker"` tiggers a jQuery calendar that inputs dates in mm/dd/yy format.

Here is my javascript code that checks if the due date has been filled:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var due_date = $('#datepicker').val();

if (due_date === "") {
$(".alert").html('Please select a due date.');
$("#datepicker").focus();

} else {
// Submit form
}
});
```

Although this does stop the user and asks for a date to be chosen, the script doesn't recognize that the user has already entered a date.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But the code above executes after DOM was loaded. Shouldn't you add an event handler on the input field?

Comment: It actually gets triggered on submit. I just left that part out of the code. Sorry!

Comment: Hmmm... Two suggestions. 1) Try with if( == ) instead of ===. 2) Try, instead of getting the date with .val(), to use something like $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});.